# Holomorphicity of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ be holomorphic and non-constant. Define $g(z) = f\big(\frac1z\big)$, for $z\ne0$. Is it possible to define $g(0)$ so that $g : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ is holomorphic?

Answer (score 2):

If so, then $f(z)\to g(0)$ as $z\to\infty$, meaning that $f$ is bounded, hence constant.

Comment: And hence, holomorphic? Would that be the whole proof?

Comment: Constant, which you assumed it wasn't.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by that

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are able to define $g(0)$ such that $g$ is holomorphic.

Then we shall have $$g(0)=\lim_{z \to 0} g(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}f\left( \frac {1}{z}\right)=\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)$$
So we have $f$ bounded outside a compact ball around zero ( say $B[0,M]$, for some $M>0$ )by the definition of limit.Again $f$ being entire  it is bounded on that compact ball ( consequence of continuity of $f$ on $B[0,M]$)

Hence $f$ is bounded on all of $\mathbb C$.
So $f$ being bounded entire you have $f$ is constant function(by Lioville's theorem), which is not possible.

You can't define $g(0)$ so that $g$ is holomorphic.